# Making a game in python called Othello its a real game. Cannot change specific values in a array

Tags: python, arrays

This is a 8 by 8 array the problem is when I set the variable player_2_move to the row and column which is input we get from the user the value of that variable stays at 0 when its meant to go to the two inputs we get. And from there I don't know how to change the value which Is Player 2 move this only happens when a function which checks for a winning move is checked. The two inputs work when I call the drop piece function which is most confusing. And also I'm still drafting with arrays which is why the numbers are 1 and 2.
The game I'm making is called Othello.

````
import pygame, sys
import math

pygame.init()
ROW_COUNT = 8
COLUMN_COUNT = 8
PLAYER_COUNT = 2

RED = (255, 0, 0)
BEIGE = (255, 200, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

SQUARESIZE = 100

width = COLUMN_COUNT * SQUARESIZE
height = ROW_COUNT * SQUARESIZE

size = (width, height)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(RED)

# Vertical
one_x_1 = 100
one_y_1 = 0

one_end_x = 100
one_end_y = 800

# Horizontal
two_x_1 = 0
two_y_1 = 100

two_end_x = 800
two_end_y = 100

RADIUS = int(SQUARESIZE/2 - 5)


def draw_board(board):
    global one_x_1, one_y_1, one_end_x, one_end_y, two_x_1, two_y_1, two_end_x, two_end_y
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, (one_x_1, one_y_1), (one_end_x, one_end_y), 3)
            one_x_1 += 100
            one_end_x += 100
        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, (two_x_1, two_y_1), (two_end_x, two_end_y), 3)
        two_y_1 += 100
        two_end_y += 100
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (int(c*SQUARESIZE+SQUARESIZE/2), height - int(r*SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE/2)), RADIUS)
            elif board[r][c] == 2:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (int(c*SQUARESIZE+SQUARESIZE/2), height - int(r*SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE/2)), RADIUS)
    pygame.display.update()


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.remaining_pieces = 32
        self.number = number


board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT), dtype=np.uint8)
board[3][3] = 1
board[4][4] = 1
board[3][4] = 2
board[4][3] = 2

print(board)

draw_board(board)
pygame.display.update()

players = [Player(i) for i in range(1, PLAYER_COUNT + 1)]
print(len(players))

game_over = False

while not game_over:
    # Event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        for p in players:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                posx = event.pos[0]
                posy = event.pos[1]
                column = int(math.floor(posx/SQUARESIZE))
                row = int(math.floor(posy/SQUARESIZE))

                if board[row][column] == 0:
                    board[row][column] = p.number
                    p.remaining_pieces = p.remaining_pieces - 1

                    # The eight directions in which we will go
                    directions = [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, -1), (0, 1), (0, -1)]

                    for d in directions:
                        x = row
                        y = column
                        while True:
                            x = x + d[0]  # Assign x to the first value in the tuple
                            y = y + d[1]  # Assign y to the second value in the tuple

                            # check if we are still on the board
                            if (x in range(8)) and (y in range(8)):

                                print(f'checking y = {x + 1}, x = {y + 1}')
                                # if the file is empty there are no pieces to capture
                                if board[x][y] == 0:
                                        break
                                """
                                If we find a number around our move we run the same procedure for it and change it 
                                if we have to
                                """
                                if p.number == board[x][y]:  # Here p.number is the players move we find it on the board
                                    print(f'found {p.number}: y = {x + 1}, x = {y + 1}')
                                    i = row
                                    j = column
                                    while i != x or j != y:
                                        i = i + d[0]
                                        j = j + d[1]
                                        print(f'changed : y = {i + 1}, x = {j + 1} to {p.number}')
                                        board[i][j] = p.number
                            else:
                                # We are outside the board
                                break
                draw_board(board)
                print(board)```
````

Comment: When you call `is_valid_location(board, column, row)` and the location is not valid, the next turn starts nonetheless. You should create a second `while True` loop to keep checking until there is a valid location. To help you more we would need your `is_valid_location`, `winning_move_player` and `drop_piece` functions so we can understand how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you a lot I'm quite new to programming this is my first attempt at a solo project. And incase you Misunderstoodd the valid_location function only checks if the coordinates we give in are in the size of the array which is 8 x 8. The winning move player checks if a piece is meant to be taken out. I'm gonna post the functions in a little bit bit just know that the winning_move_player is very mechinal and will probably look very Unpythonic. Should I just put the whole code.

Comment: Can you see my other comment?

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to see the whole code. Now regarding the `is_valid_location(board, column, row)` I think if somebody inputs a wrong location you probably don't want to just skip his turn, but rather reask him for the coordinates. At the moment a wrong location just results in ending the turn.

Comment: Sorry my computer is slow and constantly resets on its own

Comment: Do you know why the variable player_2_mive defaults to 0 even though its meant to be the coordinates of the players input

Comment: I'm editing this code to be the whole thing.

Comment: The computer is still buggy sorry

Comment: It's now the full code on this question

Comment: Again the main problem is that in order to change a specific value from 1 into a 2 I need its coordinates when I put the variable player_2_move into the numpy where function it shows every coordinate which has a value of zero. But I need it to have the players move which has to be converted into the opposite players number

Comment: And since the player_move_2 is assigned only if the winning function call is bypassed so thats why I think only the coordinates the coordinates of the value which has to be converted into another number should be returned

Comment: Hello can you please answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go step by step through your program and improve it.
First of all creating arrays like this:

```
player1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
player2 = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Is always a bad practice. Since you already use numpy in your project it's easy to create them like this:

```
player1 = np.ones(32, dtype=np.uint8)
player2 = np.full(32, 2, dtype=np.uint8)
```

However you don't really need those arrays anyway. You can just have an integer which keeps track of the remaining pieces. `reamining_pieces = 32`
To make the whole think easier I created a Player class which contains a Player number and the remaining Pieces.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.remaining_pieces = 32
        self.number = number
```

Now after this you have a lot of functions which aren't really necessary. They are so simple that there is no advantage of writing a function for them.
So for example instead of writing

```
def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT))
    return board
board = create_board()
```

It's a lot simpler and easier to read if you just write

```
board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT))
```

Same goes for `def drop_piece(board, row, col, piece)` and `def is_valid_location(board, row, col)` which both just add unnecessary complexity to it.

## Step by step explanation

First, we start with a tuple of all directions:

```
directions = [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, -1), (0, 1), (0, -1)]
```

[image: All eight directions two dimensions]

And we now want to go in all directions and every time we start at `row, column` which is where the newly placed piece is located.

```
for d in directions:
    x = row
    y = column
```

And since we don't know how far we have to go we use a while loop and take the first step in the direction. Because We don't want to go outside of the board we immediately check if we are still on the board. If we are, we can continue.

```
while True:
    x = x + d[0]
    y = y + d[1]

    # check if we are still on the board
    if (x in range(8)) and (y in range(8)):
```

For the following steps let's use this as an example:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 * 2 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

The star is where has just been placed a one. If we go one step to the left, we will encounter a 0 and know that we don't have to go any further. That's what

```
if board[x][y] == 0:
    break
```

Does.
If we now go to the right. We will first encounter a two and it just get's ignored and we go one step further to the right.
Here we finally find a one. So we know that between `row, column` and `x, y` every number can be converted to a one. To do that we start at `row, column` and move once again until we reach `x, y`. On the way we convert every number to a one:

```
if p.number == board[x][y]:
    print(f'found {p.number}: x = {x + 1}, y = {y + 1}')
    i = row
    j = column
    while i != x or j != y:
        i = i + d[0]
        j = j + d[1]
        print(f'changed : x = {i + 1}, y = {j + 1} to {p.number}')
        board[i][j] = p.number
```

## Whole Code

```
import pygame, sys
import math
import numpy as np

pygame.init()
ROW_COUNT = 8
COLUMN_COUNT = 8
PLAYER_COUNT = 2

RED = (255, 0, 0)
BEIGE = (255, 200, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

SQUARESIZE = 100

width = COLUMN_COUNT * SQUARESIZE
height = ROW_COUNT * SQUARESIZE

size = (width, height)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.fill(RED)

# Vertical
one_x_1 = 100
one_y_1 = 0

one_end_x = 100
one_end_y = 800

# Horizontal
two_x_1 = 0
two_y_1 = 100

two_end_x = 800
two_end_y = 100

RADIUS = int(SQUARESIZE / 2 - 5)


def draw_board(board):
    global one_x_1, one_y_1, one_end_x, one_end_y, two_x_1, two_y_1, two_end_x, two_end_y
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, (one_x_1, one_y_1), (one_end_x, one_end_y), 3)
            one_x_1 += 100
            one_end_x += 100
        pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, (two_x_1, two_y_1), (two_end_x, two_end_y), 3)
        two_y_1 += 100
        two_end_y += 100
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (
                int(c * SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE / 2), height - int(r * SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE / 2)), RADIUS)
            elif board[r][c] == 2:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (
                int(c * SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE / 2), height - int(r * SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE / 2)), RADIUS)
    pygame.display.update()


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.remaining_pieces = 32
        self.number = number


board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT), dtype=np.uint8)
board[3][3] = 1
board[4][4] = 1
board[3][4] = 2
board[4][3] = 2

print(board)

draw_board(board)
pygame.display.update()

players = [Player(i) for i in range(1, PLAYER_COUNT + 1)]
print(len(players))


def next_player():
    while True:
        for player in players:
            yield player


player_generator = next_player()

game_over = False

while not game_over:
    # Event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            posx = event.pos[0]
            posy = event.pos[1]
            column = int(math.floor(posx / SQUARESIZE))
            row = int(math.floor(posy / SQUARESIZE))

            p = player_generator.__next__()

            if board[row][column] == 0:
                board[row][column] = p.number
                p.remaining_pieces = p.remaining_pieces - 1

                # The eight directions in which we will go
                directions = [(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (1, -1), (0, 1), (0, -1)]

                for d in directions:
                    x = row
                    y = column
                    while True:
                        x = x + d[0]  # Assign x to the first value in the tuple
                        y = y + d[1]  # Assign y to the second value in the tuple

                        # check if we are still on the board
                        if (x in range(8)) and (y in range(8)):

                            print(f'checking y = {x + 1}, x = {y + 1}')
                            # if the file is empty there are no pieces to capture
                            if board[x][y] == 0:
                                break
                            """
                            If we find a number around our move we run the same procedure for it and change it 
                            if we have to
                            """
                            if p.number == board[x][y]:  # Here p.number is the players move we find it on the board
                                print(f'found {p.number}: y = {x + 1}, x = {y + 1}')
                                i = row
                                j = column
                                while i != x or j != y:
                                    i = i + d[0]
                                    j = j + d[1]
                                    print(f'changed : y = {i + 1}, x = {j + 1} to {p.number}')
                                    board[i][j] = p.number
                        else:
                            # We are outside the board
                            break
            draw_board(board)
            print(board)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226219/discussion-on-answer-by-abrogans-making-a-game-in-python-called-othello-its-a-re).